# Incompatibility SSD vs bios?

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

I've an American Megatrends bios version 2.15.1227 installed on notebook Asus F552CL. I've replaced the default HD with a SSD (a SanDisk Extreme PRO 240GB) the bios recognize the new device (it show the SSD in the devices section) but the SSD is not shown in the boot options?

Why? Is this a BIOS problem? Could a BIOS update have effects?

I've tried to disable secure boot, enable CSM, set SATA configuration to AHCI but nothing works. Help me!

Comment: "the bios correctly understand the new device but I can't see it in boot options" - So the SSD does show up in the BIOS but just not in the boot order menu?

Comment: Yes. Edited. Check now,.

Comment: "Could a BIOS update have effects?" - If you're asking whether a BIOS update might fix this issue, the answer is: possibly. No harm in trying as long as you don't mess up the flashing process.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop boots in EUFI mode but the SSD does not have a [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), it can't find any partitions to boot from. Changes are the disk has an old style MBR (Master Boot Record), or no partition at all. Or the other way around: the BIOS boots in legacy mode and the SSD has a GPT and a dummy MBR.

To fix this, you must boot from an external media (USB stick, CDROM) with a Linux or Windows system and create the partition table (Windows parlance is 'initialize the disk'). Or, mount the SSD temporarely in an external USB housing, hook it up to a working system and create the proper partition table there.

On Windows 8, go to Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Computer Management (run as Administrator). In Storage Management go to Disk Management and select your external harddisk there. There you should be able to create a GPT or MBR partition.

I'd wait with BIOS updates until nothing else works.

Comment: Why do you believe a BIOS update would fix this problem?  Because this problem as you correct point out, has nothing, to do with the firmware.

Comment: How do I initialize the disk's MBR? Can I initialize the MBR of USB plugged disk (my SSD in this case)?

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea, I've read of some problem with a sort of sleep mode that is not present on older BIOS and I've asked for confirm.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think you're reading too much into the last sentence.  Not precluding a BIOS update, even if it's not expected to help, doesn't make this a bad answer.

Comment: @Mariano - You cannot use MBR if you want to boot Windows in non-legacy EFI mode.  You need to boot to an EFI optical disk or USB device and create the partition which will contain the required EFI drivers on the drive itself.

Comment: @fixer1234 - That is only one of the problems I have, in my opionion, the answer does not fully explain HOW the user acomplishes what is described.

Comment: Ok. So supposed I've started Windows 8 with old HD mounted. Then I plug into USB port the SSD (through a SATA box). Right now how I "create the partition which will contain the required EFI drivers"???

Comment: I updated the answer. My last line about a BIOS update is that I don't expect an incompatibility with your SSD, and therefor I would wait with updating the BIOS (always a tricky operation) as a last resort. BTW, you don't "install EFI drivers" on the disk. It is actually easier to install Windows from DVD/CD to a blank SSD as that will create all the required partions so you can actually boot from it (should have realised that...)

Comment: This is all that I can do: http://postimg.org/image/q2h5y6867/ Nothing to do with a bootable option. Help! :'(

Comment: Right-click on "Disk 1" in the lower half...

Comment: There's one choice ''Convert as dynamic disk''.